# Not able see anything on RDB screen after ending an explorer.exe task

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008

I accidentally ended an `explorer.exe` task for a Windows Server 2008 R2 on the remote desktop connection. After that I can't see anything on RDP.

How do I restore again to get back all the icons on desktop and Task Manager? No keys are working like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> for RDP. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Perform the following to restart `explorer.exe`.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to bring up the Windows Security dialog.
2. Click "Start Task Manager"
3. Click File, New Task (Run...)
4. Type `explorer.exe` in the box.
5. Click OK